# Updating IndepVarComp within a component inside the group

Tags: openmdao

This may be a question due to my lack of knowledge python but I would like to add_output to indepvarcomp (that has been initiated at the problem or group level) from within a component that is one level lower in the hieararchy. A sample code can be something like this (see below) and looking at the connections that variable is not recognized. Is it possible to do this?

```
from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver, IndepVarComp,Group,ExplicitComponent

class SellarDis2(ExplicitComponent):
    from openmdao.core.indepvarcomp import IndepVarComp

    def initialize(self):
        self.options.declare('indeps', types=IndepVarComp)

    def setup(self):

        indeps=self.options['indeps']
        indeps.add_output('try', 1.0)
        self.add_input('try', val=2)
        self.add_input('z', val=2)

        self.add_output('y2',  val=5.0)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        outputs['y2'] = inputs['z']*2+inputs['try']


class SellarMDA(Group):

    def setup(self):
        indeps = self.add_subsystem('indeps', IndepVarComp(), promotes=['*'])
        indeps.add_output('z', 1.0)

        self.add_subsystem('d2', SellarDis2(indeps=indeps), promotes=['*'])



prob = Problem()
prob.model = SellarMDA()

prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'COBYLA'
# prob.driver.options['maxiter'] = 100
prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-8

prob.model.add_design_var('z', lower=0, upper=10)
#prob.model.add_objective('obj')


prob.setup()


prob.run_model()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, the provided script does not work. Thought I agree that in theory it seems like this should work and is a minor bug of sorts, I also do not think you should actually build a model this way.

I don't understand why the child component needs to create the variable at the parent level. In OpenMDAO, children don't know anything about their parents by design. We're pretty strict about enforcing that within the internals of the framework code and in models themselves.

If you needed to add an new independent variable at some lower level of the hierarchy (that certainly does happen) then I suggest you create a group at that lower level and a new IndepVarComp to hold the new variable. Here is an edited version of your script with how I suggest you handle the situation.

```
from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver, IndepVarComp, Group, ExplicitComponent

class SellarDis2(ExplicitComponent):


    def setup(self):

        self.add_input('try', val=2)
        self.add_input('z', val=2)

        self.add_output('y2',  val=5.0)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        outputs['y2'] = inputs['z']*2+inputs['try']


class SubGroup(Group):

    def setup(self):
        indeps = self.add_subsystem('indeps', IndepVarComp(), promotes=['*'])
        indeps.add_output('try', 1.0)
        self.add_subsystem('d2', SellarDis2(), promotes=['*'])

class SellarMDA(Group):

    def setup(self):
        indeps = self.add_subsystem('indeps', IndepVarComp(), promotes=['*'])
        indeps.add_output('z', 1.0)

        self.add_subsystem('d2', SubGroup(), promotes=['*'])



prob = Problem()
prob.model = SellarMDA()

prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'COBYLA'
# prob.driver.options['maxiter'] = 100
prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-8

prob.model.add_design_var('z', lower=0, upper=10)
#prob.model.add_objective('obj')


prob.setup()
prob.final_setup()


prob.run_model()
```

I followed your naming conventions, and just to be clear I created a **second** IndepVarComp within the sub-group, but still with the same name. Here is an N2 to make the model structure clear. [image: N2 diagram of example model]